# Error when opening product window in openbavo

Tags: product, openbravo

How can this be resolved?.

I restored DB backup and code backup from production server to test server, Then I executed ant export.database, then smart build. Everything is successful.

But product window or any thing that is related to product is not displayed. when opened product window in openbravo, I got the  error as in screenshot.

Please respond if any solution is there. Thanks in advance.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE5Rr.png]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, export.database wont help you. You should:

1. Update database `ant update.database`
2. Perform a complete deploy, as gorozcoh suggested `ant compile.complete.deploy`
3. Restart tomcat (if you are under ubuntu `sudo service-tomcat restart` or `sudo service openbravo-tomcat restart`)

Neither export.database nor ant smartbuild will update the database and if you don't restart tomcat you are not going anywhere either :-)

Hope it helps,

Regards

PS: Refer - http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Development_Build_Tasks

Answer (score 0):

Try executing ant compile.complete.deploy.

Comment: Can you elaborate why that answers the question?